# Invalid release error when uploading config file to cloudfoundry

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, release, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to upload a release to cloud foundry (following [these steps](http://elsoufy.blogspot.fr/2015/02/installing-cloud-foundry-v2-locally-on.html) for the complete cf installation) after installing `bosh-lite`. The process failed due to an invalid release as shown below, i tried with different configs cf-200.yml and cf-199.yml.
I'm using ubuntu desktop 14.04.2.

What I can do?

```
$ bosh upload release cf-release/releases/cf-200.yml

Copying packages
----------------
hm9000 (ce5b3ae4b0fa4ece6c5e741fd9b675751e78eb73)
uaa (263a72b91dfb6e4e9a2983e50694b5536e81c0bb)
haproxy (630ad6d6e1d3cab4547ce104f3019b483f354613)
loggregator_trafficcontroller (cc2a209b2256500f987001771c0443b48a722780)
buildpack_python (0c0bf75e84a4a57080619175ed2e9d3bb48397c3)
syslog_drain_binder (8c627a89c81b429ea065ca86cf603204ba5eb6af)
rootfs_lucid64 (362ed9221fbdae9cd3f889088fc373b04f04cb8f)
buildpack_php (6ee814b62c4f7a587fdb75f0aeee6775cbb95690)
buildpack_java_offline (0386a6f0df31247acf5a077a6b2051ec9546d641)
acceptance-tests (0bfc921229a8bd4fada3aff13a0da387e3287324)
buildpack_nodejs (d243df46ac9056320914ca1d6843e112b309720d)
buildpack_go (cb35d33ef9d379246bcdcccdad7858f8f37ab8cb)
postgres (b63fe0176a93609bd4ba44751ea490a3ee0f646c)
golang1.3 (e4b65bcb478d9bea1f9c92042346539713551a4a)
smoke-tests (d1aaf8be8786ee2ee001ce0a30d154c268f770fc)
ruby-2.1.4 (5a4612011cb6b8338d384acc7802367ae5e11003)
login (f2f60e4ae26ec74ddb2b6ae50aefe47517267fab)
golang (aa5f90f06ada376085414bfc0c56c8cd67abba9c)
ruby (cd102a7fe440fd9eaeee99c6bc460b06884cbda6)
etcd_metrics_server (64efbbfb5761d09a24dad21ecfebd8824b99d433)
etcd (44df7612404c5b2ecc1f167126b9e0b20481f79d)
metron_agent (17b67c312bd6f5483a6cbbbfc3c42aca57088b1a)
nginx_newrelic_plugin (92f2c6fb3f807f030d989c52cd1de445eba3f296)
dea_next (eab1b7674e16dc7d73d0d085e8fe48e2cc7e1e9c)
buildpack_java (9b8537ab662d136ce449dc8715344ea77b24c714)
gnatsd (a0d6f5d3264aa8ecadb52d3bfa04540636800820)
mysqlclient (8b5d9ce287341048377997a9b3fe4ff3e6a1c68f)
nats (cc6bda829a77ab2321c0c216aa9107aca92c3b1a)
buildpack_cache (4ced0bc62f12dcaa79121718ca3525253ede33b5)
libpq (49cc7477fcf9a3fef7a1f61e1494b32288587ed8)
nginx (c916c10937c83a8be507d3100133101eb403c826)
collector (9fa967f02b3dacc621369babb1a5e0b7940a9c80)
cli (8870a5c3c03b4d4f2e190c3d81e3805d8b2e100a)
doppler (554c3407d12b98e7175417af2db2e0eab977344c)
gorouter (68a763ef18b39c6dc2539d2a733e1721b7fa9556)
debian_nfs_server (aac05f22582b2f9faa6840da056084ed15772594)
cloud_controller_ng (02b6f1b3979031871c4821ccc911748aef03c4f1)
common (43595236d1ce5f9a6120198108c226c07ab17012)
dea_logging_agent (d0dba8b83454a52ebe60794d13f834243f4c932f)
buildpack_ruby (45668ee6b3d2777393c85807c9456e6f3437f481)
warden (7d6d68c3f52d9a0925171f879e953b352bbf1325)

Copying jobs
------------
hm9000 (ce489a0832c861792af65667c161e0857bd5c8fa)
uaa (22afa59fe263b5f4aa00c805fbe611f245c14dc1)
haproxy (34444281e2b8bf1e41b07b4a5cb088a838fbc1b7)
loggregator_trafficcontroller (e834d50a64ac3b9859418582a6fac9deaf0a31b0)
syslog_drain_binder (d1cef58efbc1504e9b6f5b6aeb5a1f387ac82c40)
cloud_controller_clock (bfa3cba64856c41af3a7e7ecb96087da058e6cb9)
nfs_mounter (e597e616003791ea243cf1d49880a90088c1129e)
acceptance-tests (329da167ab6e15d62ae3bbe381bf10f83b2a9bde)
cloud_controller_worker (27f568fdb914c91a1f626b3dfbfbe0d4f0b0ec43)
postgres (20e9a42637977ff968b075776a3d8e6a578b0503)
smoke-tests (13bbe1a4398c4b9c948b77bf577ed7e0c72146b1)
login (cd1a4a104793ee1d056185cc048e8ccd5f81d78a)
etcd_metrics_server (bdf9fa22da62d0b08c4d867c3a1285fc355290ef)
etcd (79b92026e3dbfa40439693f0293f50910125ceb6)
metron_agent (4cf0a43aa50c72ea4dd4538f7289aa97f68de3cd)
dea_next (ad65eb4e0bfa431eae989e447688daae6560047c)
nats (7df4984a72d0f5a375da6d1548ac51fa15ade965)
collector (43b67fee22ef25f6e8958d92035bcd4a499bb975)
doppler (3b52db93b7a71973799b1abf2419ce927a6e94b0)
gorouter (9fb12603f22db304fa294c2754fe07b762f70aa7)
debian_nfs_server (3ddad2bb1faa5f424697821db8353f76dfc30d73)
cloud_controller_ng (794d116d310fdb1e34d3f352597f6e698448a6bd)
dea_logging_agent (4d4a96b62bea490993fc8c25f04032133815c152)
nats_stream_forwarder (0f7a5da9369b2baf5a46c2a9af4c75f14d09afd3)

Copying license
---------------

Building tarball
----------------
Generated /tmp/d20150225-3446-16fws4k/d20150225-3446-1sxorcl/release.tgz
Release size: 3.8G

Verifying release...
File exists and readable                                     OK
Extract tarball                                              FAILED

Release is invalid, please fix, verify and upload again
```

The disk usage is as follows:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        24G   14G  9,1G  60% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3,9G  4,0K  3,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           799M  1,2M  798M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            3,9G   76K  3,9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sr0        996M  996M     0 100% /media/arbi/Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that your /tmp folder is not too low on space and if it is, try setting TMPDIR in your command first:

`TMPDIR=/some/where/bigger bosh upload release ...`

Comment: it's a space problem as stated in this [issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/issues/23), I had to mount a virtual disk and use it to hold TMPDIR.